# Tap action on stack view not working properly when text field selected for iOS with Nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript

So I'm using Nativescript to create app for both Android and iOS and I'm having some problems with iOS.

So I have a stack view where I have added a tap action, called "closeKeyboard" (currently just log message to console).
Inside the stack view I have text field.
The problem is that when I press on the text field, the stack view action also gets triggered.

On Android it works as expected - selecting text field doesn't trigger stack view action.

Here is the code for main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <StackLayout tap="closeKeyboard">
    <Label class="conf-button-label" text="Netto sum" />
    <TextField text="{{ sum }}" hint="Type number" returnKeyType="done" keyboardType="number" keyboardPatter="[0-9]*" returnPress="done" id="sum" col="0" row="0"  class=""/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Here is a code for main-page.js

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    page = args.object;
}

function done(){
    console.log('Input Done');
}


function closeKeyboard(page){
    console.log('Close Keyboard Tapped');
}
exports.done = done;
exports.closeKeyboard = closeKeyboard;
exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to create something like javascript blur event or just to hide keyboard, when you tap outside the TextView, you could set custom gesture for ios using native code. You could review the bellow attached example:

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded">
  <StackLayout id="stack">
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <TextView id="text" text="" hint="Enter some text" backgroundColor="yellow" updateTextTrigger="focusLost"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.js

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;
var gestures = require("ui/gestures");
var observableModule = require("data/observable"); 
var observableObject = new observableModule.Observable();

var TapHandlerImpl1 = (function (_super) {
    __extends(TapHandlerImpl1, _super);
    function TapHandlerImpl1() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    TapHandlerImpl1.initWithOwner = function (owner) {
        var handler = TapHandlerImpl1.new();
        handler._owner = owner;
        return handler;
    };
    TapHandlerImpl1.prototype.tap = function () {
        this._owner.ios.resignFirstResponder();
    };
    TapHandlerImpl1.ObjCExposedMethods = {
        "tap": { returns: interop.types.void, params: [interop.types.id] }
    };
    return TapHandlerImpl1;
}(NSObject));

var tapHandler = null;

function loaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var field = page.getViewById("text");
    if (page.ios) {
        tapHandler = TapHandlerImpl1.initWithOwner(field)
        var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.alloc().initWithTargetAction(tapHandler, "tap");
        page.ios.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
    }

    field.addEventListener(observableModule.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(pcd){
        console.log(pcd.eventName.toString() + " " + pcd.propertyName.toString() + " " + pcd.value.toString());
    });

    page.bindingContext = observableObject; } 
exports.loaded = loaded;
```

However the same problem have been discussed also in [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2376) GitHub issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped me a lot. But, maybe you know how can i do some actions, when keyboard was closed? In my current project calculation is done only when i press "Done" in my keyboard, but it would be awesome to submit my input after keyboard is closed. I believe in IOS it's called UIKeyboardWillHideNotification

Comment: You could add property change event listener to the textfield. In this case you should also add `updateTextTrigger="focusLost"` to the textfield, which will returns you the whole value from the text property, only when the textfield loses focus.

Comment: You could review the article here - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events#propertychange-event

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to move the `closeKeyboard()` from Stacklayout to the child view Label. Or you can try to define a separate tap action for the textfield to override the tap action of stacklayout.